# Drag and Drop DropEffect style

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

Is there an easy way to change the regular drag and drop style of a ListBoxItem to make it look different? I'm talking about the style that shows the "Don't" sign, the + and the little rectangle in the cursor when you drag over another control.

The style used by default is too 'ugly' and simple, we would like to show some information when a drop is about to occur. How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

EDIT:

BTW. I already tried this solution[Shell Style Drag and Drop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adamroot/archive/2008/02/19/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-part-3.aspx), we don't want the drag and drop to interact with the OS, only within the application.

I also tried setting an Adorner on top of the cursor. The Adorner renders certain visuals that move with the cursor, but that only works if we don't call the DragDrop.DoDragDrop method. The Adorner stops moving right after we call that mehod.

Answer (score 2):

[This example](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/drag-drop-using-listboxes-part-2/) uses an Adorner to show a preview of the ListBoxItem and calls DragDrop.DoDragDrop. Is that the one you tried?

Comment: Definitely not the one I tried. This looks promising, I'll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @Carlo - Ok, cool. If memory serves, the only limitation was if the two ListBoxes did not share a common visual ancestor then the adorner could not be used.

Comment: The link is not available to me. As no small code example is provided, this answer has now very limited usefulness.